# How to convert a string with some lines to a list that every cell contains one line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a variable `string` with string type like this:

```
string = """First
Second
Third
..."""
```

I want to add every line to a separate cell of a list, because this variable size change by I can't use something like this:

```
temp=[]
temp.append(s[0:5])
....
```

And I didn't find any helpful function that separate lines for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a built-in function for this: `str.split`. It returns a list of string containing the whole passed string which is cut accordingly to a given character. For example:

```
>>> "foo bar foobar".split(' ')
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

Here, I want to use the space as separator. In your case, you want to have every different line in a single string. So, the separator is a new line character, in python represente by the `\n` character. So, all you have to do is:

```
lines_list = s.split('\n')
```

But, that depends on what OS you're using your program: on Unix based systems, normally all will work. But, Windows has chosen to use a carriage return (`\r` in python) *and* a line feed (`n`) for lines separator. So, if you apply the previous code on a Windows system, you'll have a list which looks like `['foo\r', 'bar\r', 'foobar\r']`. The problem is that the presence of carriage returns may cause some issues, you have to remove them, doing for example this:

```
lines_list = [line.replace('\r', '') for line in lines_list]
```

Basically, this line of code create a new list (using a comprehension list) which contains all the elements of `lines_list`, but where `\r` has been replaced by... nothing, so has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Just do splitting according to the newline charcater.

```
string.split("\n")
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s="""temp
bar
foo"""
>>> s.split("\n")
['temp', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
s.split('\n')
```

If `\n` doesn't work for some reasons you can try `\r\n` as well. It depends on the system that you are using.

You may get results like this:

```
['First', 'Second', 'Third', '']
```

If you find such empty strings and want to ignore them, try:

```
[x for x in s.split('\n') if x]
```

Your results will change to:

```
['First', 'Second', 'Third']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like -

```
temp = s.split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import re
In [6]: a = re.compile('[\s\n\r]')

In [7]: a.split('asf sfd ww3 ')
Out[7]: ['asf', 'sfd', 'ww3', '']

In [9]: string = '''asfdasdf
   ...: ass
   ...: fdsf ssdaf
   ...: dsf s a
   ...: '''
In [10]: a.split(string)
Out[10]: ['asfdasdf', 'ass', 'fdsf', 'ssdaf', 'dsf', 's', 'a', '']
```